# How to Automate Sending Whatsapp Messages on Python WITHOUT webdriver or twilio?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, twilio, whatsapp

I am trying to program a service that automatically sends WhatsApp Messages to anyone without manual intervention. How can I automate this without human intervention?

I have tried using Twilio, but I believe you have to pay to avail the full features (and I'm not really ready to spend money on this wee mini-project), and although I can achieve this through selenium's webdriver, I need to first scan the QR Code, which doesn't really make it fully automated.

Comment: :Facebook providing bussiness api for For medium and large businesses.. Are you expecting same? If yes Using API means not matter what programming language!

Comment: send the gets/posts required by the API.